# Best approach for Color Touch Effects

Tags: android, image, image-processing

There are many apps in the market which allows you to apply image effects such as black&white to your photos while touching it. What is the best approach to achieve this kind of functionality.

My idea is the following:

Create at first the image with the desired effect (e.g black&white or sepia) and place it under the original image. In the onTouch method I can erase the pixel from the original image, so I can see the effect in the touched area.

Is this an efficient approach, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want black and white, you simply have to assign (0,0,0) to the RGB values of the pixels within the touched region if they are below a threshold (e.g. 255/2) or (255,255,255) if they are above or equal this threshold.

However, if by black and white you mean a grayscale image, a better solution would be to convert the RGB image to [HSL color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). To get the adequate graylevel, just set the pixel Saturation (S) to 0. This is nice, because you can a kind of gradient effect on the touched region: set S to 0 to pixels exactly below the touch point and let the decrease on the S value be lower with respect to the distance to the touch point.

To get the sepia effect, I believe that you will also need to change de Hue (H) value.